# Which ALD file need to select in Import label files into the model store during upgradation

Tags: upgrade, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am doing upgradation from AX2009 to AX2012 R3 CU11, I have doubt on Import label files into the model store in the code upgrade checklist. Here which label file I need to select like, Is EN-US ALD label file enough or else need to import all ALD files(different languages)? Can  you suggest please,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer,We have to import all Customized ALD files into target system